# Cannot see user desktop (Applications, Places, System...) when I log in

Tags: virtualbox, appmenu, system-tray

I am very new to Ubuntu. I recently got a new laptop running Windows 7. I am using Virtual Box and just installed the Ubuntu 12.10 ISO as a new Virtual Machine within Virtual Box. Everything seemed to install just fine and I even added the Guest Additions under Devices.

The problem is that I cannot see the menus and my login information.  The virtual machine says it is running; however, I do not have the **Applications**, **Places**, **System**, etc. tray to select from.  Is there something I am supposed to do after logging in to get this?  I entered my password and everything seemed fine, I just don't have those drop-down menus available...

Comment: You probably need this question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 2):

Those menus have been phased out ever since the introduction of [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) (circa **Ubuntu Netbook 10.10**). You should see a launcher bar on the left. If for some reason it's hidden (or set to Autohide), strike the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to reveal it. If your Virtual Machine is not configured to capture the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, hover your mouse along the left side of the screen.

The top icon (with the Ubuntu logo) will, once clicked, reveal your Applications, Files, Places, etc in a new, [debatably] user-friendly manner.

If you miss the old style menus, you can always [switch back to Gnome Classic](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-classic-gnome-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html).